# Powershell - Fastest way to write large body of text to a file

Tags: powershell

In terms of runtime performance, which is the fastest method in powershell to write a large body of text into a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$sw = new-object system.IO.StreamWriter(<my file path>)
$sw.write(<my large body of text>)
$sw.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

Guillaume Bordier wrote a nice [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/gbordier/archive/2009/05/05/powershell-and-writing-files-how-fast-can-you-write-to-a-file.aspx) about the different methods of writing to a file.

From the article's conclusion:

```
Method               - Time to completion
‘>>’                 - 29 s
Out-file and [Array] - 27 s
export-csv           - 22 s
StreamWriter         - 1.5 s
```

The fastest way to write to a file (by a margin) is using `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Here is an article also that builds on Bordier article : https://powershelladministrator.com/2015/11/15/speed-of-loops-and-different-ways-of-writing-to-files-which-is-the-quickest/

Answer (score 0):

Definitely read the excellent article from PS admin blog (with code example).

Summary is to avoid foreach-object loop and use following for write to file:

- .net File WriteLine
- .net StreamWriter WriteLine

Link: https://www.google.com/amp/s/powershelladministrator.com/2015/11/15/speed-of-loops-and-different-ways-of-writing-to-files-which-is-the-quickest/amp/

Also a good explanation :
https://powershellexplained.com/2017-03-18-Powershell-reading-and-saving-data-to-files/#faster-reads-with-systemiofile